# Use D3 to Display SVG image within Angular Component

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I am struggling to display a simple SVG image within my Angular component using D3. I'm sure I just can't see the wood for the trees and am missing something obvious.

I have installed D3 which is listed in my `package.json` file: `"d3": "5.1.0"`. I have created an Angular Component to display the svg within and imported d3: `import * as d3 from "d3";`.

I have written a `createMap` method where I expect to append a parent element, named `svg`, to the Angular component and then append to that a child group element named `testCardGroup`. Finally I want to import my svg file and append it to the `testCardGroup` element.

I don't see the svg file displayed. perhaps I have placed the svg file in the wrong place. As I have no preceding path yet, currently it is within my `ClientApp` folder with my `package.json` and `tsconfig,json` files. Here's my code:

```
createMap() {

// Append an svg object to the base element.
this.svg = d3.select(this.element)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "svg")
  .attr("width", this.svgWidth)
  .attr("height", this.svgHeight);

// Append a new group to the svg.
this.testCardGroup = this.svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "testCardGroup")
  .attr("width", this.svgWidth)
  .attr("height", this.svgHeight);

 //Import the TestCard artwork and append to testCardGroup.
d3.xml("TestCard.svg"), function (error, xml) {
  if (error) throw error;
  this.testCardGroup.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
};
};
```

Any suggestions why the svg doesn't display very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of [`d3.xml`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#xml) has [changed](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50) from D3 v4 to v5. It has been moved from the now deprecated module d3-request to the new [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) module. As of v5 D3 uses the [Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) in favor of the older `XMLHttpRequest` and has in turn adopted the use of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to handle those asynchronous requests.

The second argument to `d3.xml()` no longer is the callback handling the request but an optional [`RequestInit`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit) object. `d3.xml()` will now return a Promise you can handle in its [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method.

Your code thus becomes:

```
d3.xml("TestCard.svg")
  .then(xml => {
    this.testCardGroup.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
  });
```